# Desktop Application with Ionic framework

Tags: ionic-framework

is there anyone who will help me about ionic framework.

I want to know that can we develop desktop and mobile application both with single codebase in ionic framework.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know that can we develop desktop and mobile application both with single codebase in ionic framework.

Yes, this is exactly the purpose of Ionic.

Check out [what is Ionic](https://ionicframework.com/what-is-ionic).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, however you will find a few Ionic components do not provide an ideal user experience on the desktop. For example, ion-datetime should probably work as a dialog on a large screen, instead uses a mobile and touch only friendly slide-up UI with selection characteristics that make number choice with a mouse quite difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Give Electron a try, on youtube search with: Ionic Framework with Electron for building Desktop Application.